# How to get param of datatable in controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, datatable, datatables

I use databale in view

```
   $("#table-DoctorClosure").DataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "@Url.Action("PaginationList", "DoctorClosure")",
            "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                aoData.push({ "name": "DoctorId", "value": @ViewBag.doctorId} );
                $.ajax({
                    type: "Get",
                    data: aoData,
                    url: sSource,
                    success: fnCallback
                })
            },
            "aoColumns": [
                { "mData": "Date" },
                { "mData": "Description" },
                {
                    "mData": "Id",
                    "className": "text-center ",
                    "render": function(Id, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<a class="btn-edit  btn btn-warning btn-sm m-l-5" href="/Doctor/DoctorClosure/Edit?id=' + Id +'" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="@OperationResource.Edit"><i class="icon-pencil" ></i> </a>' +
                            '<a class="btn-delete btn btn-sm bg-danger"  data-id="'+Id+'" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="@OperationResource.Delete"><i class="icon-trash-o"></i> </a>'
                    }
                },
            ],
            "oLanguage": {
                "sUrl": "/Content/styles/datatables/dataTables.persian.txt"
            }
        });
```

I want to get DoctorId of `aoData`

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> PaginationList(DataTableParameter param)
  {
   ???
  }
```

`DataTableParameter`  is

```
 public  class DataTableParameter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Request sequence number sent by DataTable,
    /// same value must be returned in response
    /// </summary>
    public string sEcho { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Text used for filtering
    /// </summary>
    public string sSearch { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Number of records that should be shown in table
    /// </summary>
    public int iDisplayLength { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// First record that should be shown(used for paging)
    /// </summary>
    public int iDisplayStart { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Number of columns in table
    /// </summary>
    public int iColumns { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Number of columns that are used in sorting
    /// /// </summary>
    public int iSortingCols { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Comma separated list of column names
    /// </summary>
    public string sColumns { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What version of DataTables are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood your question correctly, when you send a data to controller(with ajax or none) you should have a variable in input controller.
you send data and your `DoctorId` is not in `DataTableParameter` class. so if you want to get this param you have two solution:

**first is add DoctorId in your class(or make view model with this param):**

```
 public  class DataTableParameter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Request sequence number sent by DataTable,
    /// same value must be returned in response
    /// </summary>
    public string sEcho { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Text used for filtering
    /// </summary>
    public string sSearch { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Number of records that should be shown in table
    /// </summary>
    public int iDisplayLength { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// First record that should be shown(used for paging)
    /// </summary>
    public int iDisplayStart { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Number of columns in table
    /// </summary>
    public int iColumns { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Number of columns that are used in sorting
    /// /// </summary>
    public int iSortingCols { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Comma separated list of column names
    /// </summary>
    public string sColumns { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// if you use this you can send and use it in controller
    /// </summary>
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }
}
```

**the second way is add another param in your controller input:**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> PaginationList(DataTableParameter param, int DoctorId)
  {
   ???
  }
```